# sending post data using fopen or curl?

Tags: php, post, curl, fopen, postdata

How can I send POST data using fopen() or cURL?

Comment: If you want an answer, you have to write an actual question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that uses the PHP curl to send POST data:

```
<?

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('var1' => 'Foo', 'var2' => 'Bar');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

You can find more information on curl in [the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).